# Получение размера файла весом 40Гб

Tags: php

Используя filesize() результат "-1424707584", как можно еще получить размер больших файлов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Известная проблема тех платформ, где int оказывается 32битным. Но на сайте [php:filesize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#102135) в коментариях есть несколько способов, как узнать этот размер.

Самый простой (как по мне) способ - это выполнить `ls -l` для этого файла и аккуратно распарсить вывод. Можно также сделать запрос `stat -c "%s" имяфайла` (парсить проще)

```
exec('stat -c "%s" file.txt', $output);
$size = $output[0];
```

Да, этот способ "платформеннозависимый" (да, он только для линукс/юникс/мак), но можно написать и реализацию под другие ОСи.

Второй способ - это открыть файл на чтение и переместить указатель чтения в самый конец. А потом узнать его позицию.